# NGINX + GZIP - Altering Vary header to include User-Agent

Tags: nginx, gzip, http-headers

Currently, when nginx is set to gzip outbound content as requested by the client, the "gzip_vary on" setting will set the following header:

```
Vary: Accept-Encoding
```

We would like to modify this to send out:

```
Vary: Accept-Encoding, User-Agent
```

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Is this because of trouble with MSIE6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module [ngx_headers_more](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpHeadersMoreModule) allows you to change http headers :

```
more_set_headers -s 200 "Vary: " "Accept-Encoding, User-Agent";
```

Not tested!